# Angular: Passing Parameters from one controller to controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

wanna pass paramters (row, filteredRows (a copy of rows) and a boolean from test1controller to test2controller.
Always an assign error and undefined.

Thanx in advanced

```
<help>
</help>
```

Here's a link to my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/327nVk0svv7OktVgP8fg)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/327nVk0svv7OktVgP8fg

Comment: Could use some code snippets aside from your plnkr to point us to where your error occurs, or to give more info about your problem. Also: what have you tried until now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put: use a service for your purpose. Services can be used to store data which you can use in as many controllers as you want.

Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) link for documentation on angular services